# jQuery plug-in clone

Tags: jquery-plugins

Are there any jQuery plug-ins that can do something similar to this: [Acer Site](http://global-download.acer.com/GDHome.aspx?SC=EMEA_28&LC=en)?

I have a client who wants this functionality and not knowing what it's even called means I can't Google it and my javascript isn't good enough to clone it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the elements that slide to the right? You can just use the `animate` method. Float div elements side by side, where the initial width of the elements to the left is zero. To show a box you animate the with of an element and then show the content inside it.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">

.slideBox { float: left; margin: 2px; width: 0; height: 200px; background: #eee; }
.slideBox .content { display: none; margin: 10px; background: #ccc; }
#first { width: 100px; }
#first .content { display: block; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $('#first').click(function(){
    $('#second').animate(
      { width: '100px' },
      {complete:function(){ $('#second .content').css('display','block'); }}
    );
  });
  $('#second').click(function(){
    $('#third').animate(
      { width: '100px' },
      {complete:function(){ $('#third .content').css('display','block'); }}
    );
  });
  $('#third').click(function(){
    $('#fourth').animate(
      { width: '100px' },
      {complete:function(){ $('#fourth .content').css('display','block'); }}
    );
  });
});

</script>

<div class="slideBox" id="fourth"><div class="content">fourth</div></div>
<div class="slideBox" id="third"><div class="content">third</div></div>
<div class="slideBox" id="second"><div class="content">second</div></div>
<div class="slideBox" id="first"><div class="content">first</div></div>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I immediately overcomplicated it by thinking of it as dynamic with the boxes being created as needed.